# The proof of finding extreme points of the unit ball of $l^1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Can someone show how to start the proof of finding extreme points of the unit ball of $l^1$?

Thanks.

---

Edit: How I've done so far is that

Let $B$ be the closed unit ball of $l^1$

Consider any $x_n \in B$, so $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|x_n|=1$

Then I don't know whether I have to prove it further with contradiction or by finding its extreme points.

Thanks.

Comment: Please share your thoughts so far :)

Answer (score 3):

For example, take 
 $$
e^{(1)} = (1,0,0, \cdots )
$$
Clearly, $e^{(1)}\in B$. Now suppose that for $t \in (0,1)$, you have $b=\{ b_j \}_j , d=\{ d_j \}_j$ with $b,d \in B$ such that 
$$
e^{(1)} = t b+ ( 1- t )d
$$
Then, you must have $1=tb_1+(1-t)d_1$ and $0=tb_j+(1-t)d_j$ for $j>1$ ,which gives that 
$$
b_j=d_j=\left\{ \begin{array}{cc}
1 & \text{if } j=1  \\
0 & \text{if } j>1 \end{array} \right.
$$
Thus  $b=d=e^{(1)}$, proving that $e^{(1)}$ is an extreme point of $B$.

*Can you take it form here?* You basically only need to answer if there are any more extreme points than the $$
e^{(n)}=(\underbrace{0, \cdots, 0}_{n-1},1, 0, \cdots)
$$